# Change the location of the Auto Recovery information in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

Our local IT has our My Documents folder on a network path. This causes a problem from MSQL Server management studio as it saves it auto recovery information every 10 min it will lock up as its doing its save.

I found where VS2008 saved its setting but I can not find out how to change it out of My Documents for this. Does anyone know where that setting is located?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, at least for VS2005 and VS2008 (and I think for VS2010, but I haven't checked there), this cannot be changed from the system's "My Documents" folder.  This is terribly annoying, I agree, as we have our My Docs folder set to a network share.  When we're on VPN, the network connection is very slow, so the auto-recovery feature isn't instantaneous and blocks the UI.

I found this feedback on Microsoft Connect that indicates the inability to change the setting: [Saving Auto Recover Information in Visual Studio 2008 SP1](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=363802&wa=wsignin1.0)

There are few "alternatives."  You could, of course, turn off Auto-Recovery, but that's not generally recommended.  What I've ultimately decided to do is simply increase the time interval between auto-saves.  This is found under Tools\Options\Environment\AutoRecover (in VS2008), which is the same place you would go to turn it on/off.

Of course, in SQL Server Management Studio, there is no Environment\AutoRecover section in the options.  However, if we remember that SSMS uses the Visual Studio core (and we're comfortable with a bit of registry hacking), we can adjust the time interval for SSMS, as well.

VS uses a REG_DWORD value named "AutoRecover Save Interval" to store the number of minutes between auto-saves.  Just add that value to the following key in the registry (this is for SSMS2008).  I set mine to 60 because I don't usually do much super-critical work in SSMS, but you can set it to a value that suites you.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\General\AutoRecover

I realize this isn't really a solution to the original issue, but I think it's at least a viable alternative.

Comment: I solved this a while ago but I did exactly what you recommended so I will give you the accepted answer, I just edited the reg key to turn of auto recover (The system is very stable so I am not worried about loosing anything)

Answer (score 3):

As a follow up, with later versions of SSMS Microsoft did add Auto Recover settings in **Tools > Options > Environment > AutoRecover**.

I found recovered files on my machine at: **C:\Users<MyUserName>\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Backup Files\Solution1**