# Windows 7 pauses too often

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, windows-7-x64

My computer very often (every 15~30 mins) pauses itself, especially when I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 or Visual Studio 2010. By "pause", I mean the mouse cursor becomes the "wait" status for like 10 seconds without I taking any heavy-lifting actions on the computer.  I don't think the machine capacity is the bottleneck here, but here is the spec:

[image]

I suspect (without much confidence) maybe some sort of cache location is set on a remote location, as I see HOMEDRIVE=H:, where H: is not a physical drive on my machine but a virtual drive on the cloud which probably lives in one of our company data centers in another city.

Could anyone share some thoughts on what might be causing the "pause" problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going to throw out some suggestions here , based on what I've encountered in my enterprise dev environment.

Check in VS Tools -> Options -> Environment -> AutoRecover . Try turning Autorecover off and see if the lockup continues to happen.

Check under 'import and export settings' in the same location. are your VS settings being saved on the local drive, or a network drive somewhere? If it's a network drive, change it to a directory on one of your local drives (preferably your SSD if you have one)

Check under Debugging -> Symbols, try unchecking the 'microsoft symbol servers' from the list of .pdb locations.

Check in event viewer under Application events, to see if there is anything interesting (exceptions) happening at the exact time of your lockup.

Monitor running processes using your task manager or something with more options like sysinternals Process Explorer utility.

Comment: Thanks Tom! I will try your suggestions one by one, so that if one of them works, we can know which one.

Comment: It is the auto recovery. Details for disabling it for SQL Server Management Studio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104255/change-the-location-of-the-auto-recovery-information-in-sql-server-management-st/4234592#4234592

Comment: No problem. And that is highly annoying (the inability to reconfigure autorecovery location in SSMS). Probably overkill but worth mentioning that there are alternatives - DBArtisan is the tool I use at work instead of SSMS.